# DocuSign - File or directory not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign Rest API, and I am successfully authenticating with my developer account. I am calling a template for embedded signing, but am not getting any results. Below is the error message that I receive:

Error Message: 
`404 - File or directory not found.`

**Requests**

*URI*

`"https://demo.docusign.net/v2/accounts/bdc5a87e-d03d-449a-b03d-XXXXX/envelopes"`
`headers`

*Headers*

```
{"X-DocuSign-Authentication"=>
  "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>608d8624-47d9-44fa-b33c-XXXXX</Username><Password>XXXXXXXX</Password><IntegratorKey>XXXXX-5406c2d5-1e42-4823-b508-XXXXX</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>",
 "Accept"=>"application/json",
 "Content-Type"=>"application/json"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URI is missing `/restapi/`, -- it should look like this:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/######/envelopes

Where **######** is the Account Number corresponding to your DocuSign account (shown in the top-right corner of the UI when you're logged into the DocuSign web console):

[image: DS account id]